# Post multiple logs to DataDog with 1 HTTP request

Tags: http, post, datadog

I want to post multiple logs to DataDog from a JS function, using a single HTTP request. Looking at the v2 docs for DataDog's 'send logs' POST [endpoint](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/logs/#send-logs), it sounds like this is possible:

> For a single log request, the API ... For a multi-logs request, the API ...

But it's not clear to me from the docs how to actually send a 'multi-logs' request. I've tried the following:

```
const dataDogEndpoint = 'https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/api/v2/logs';
const body = {
    ddtags: 'env:production,status:info',
    hostname: 'my-host',
    message: ['My first production log.', 'My second production log.'],
    service: 'my-service'
};
const response = await fetch(dataDogEndpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'DD-API-KEY': apiKey
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
});
```

Perhaps unsurprisingly, this appears in DataDog as a single log with the following content:

```
[My first production log., My second production log.]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Got it - this can be achieved by adding multiple log objects to the body like so:

```
const dataDogEndpoint = 'https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/api/v2/logs';
const body = [{
        ddtags: 'env:production,status:info',
        hostname: 'my-host',
        message: 'My first production log.',
        service: 'my-service'
    },{
        ddtags: 'env:production,status:info',
        hostname: 'my-host',
        message: 'My second production log.',
        service: 'my-service'
}];
const response = await fetch(dataDogEndpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'DD-API-KEY': apiKey
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
});
```

(You'll probably want a loop instead of instantiating each log object separately.)